# Android: When a Service starts an Activity, does the activity start in a different process?

Tags: android, service

The title of the question pretty much explains the question. When I start an Activity from a service using startActivity, is this new activity started in a separate process from the service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I start an Activity from a service using startActivity, is this new activity started in a separate process from the service ?

No. All of your components share a process by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my guess is that if you start an Activity from you application, then they are in the same process, but generally system can start an activity in different process for you.
You can check your process id with
android.os.Process.myPid()
and compare it against a list of processes IDs shown in the Devices window of the Eclipse (DDMS perspective).